# axis 2 and bitnami

Tags: apache, apache-axis, bitnami

I just installed Bitnami Namp Stack 5.4.13-0. I want to get axis 2 up and running with the apache server. Is this included in the Bitnami install? if not, what do I need to do to get axis 2 working with bitnami?

Answer (score 1):

You need a Servlet container like Apache Tomcat. You cannot start axis2 ws on Apache Http Server. Bitnami also provides tomcat stack http://bitnami.com/stack/tomcat